# Chrome Android событие сворачивание браузера

Tags: javascript, события

Здравствуйте, есть событие window.onblur которые следить за фокусом вкладки, я так понимаю.
При сворачивании браузера в Windows оно тоже срабатывает, но при сворачивание браузера в Android данное событие не срабатывает , подскажите пожалуйста как можно узнать что браузер свернут на Android через JS?

Comment: Нашел вараинт решения вашего вопроса http://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/2003555. Скорее всего нужно будет допилить кочнено, но минимум можете посмотреть разные ивенты срабатывающие при измениии видимости страницы.

Comment: Оформите как ответ, помечу правильным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cледующий кросбраузерный код показывает как подписать фунцкцию `onchange` на событие изменения видимости при помощи Page Visibility API, если оно доступно. И с помощью обычных событий, если Page Visibility API не поддерживается.

```
(function() {
  var hidden = "hidden";

  // если API доступно :
  if (hidden in document)
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
  // Браузер IE 9 и ниже:
  else if ("onfocusin" in document)
    document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
  // Все прочие браузеры:
  else
    window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide
    = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

  function onchange (evt) {
    var v = "visible", h = "hidden",
        evtMap = {
          focus:v, focusin:v, pageshow:v, blur:h, focusout:h, pagehide:h
        };

    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.type in evtMap)
      document.body.className = evtMap[evt.type];
    else
      document.body.className = this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible";
  }

  // установить начальное состояние (но толко если браузер поддерживает Page Visibility API)
  if( document[hidden] !== undefined )
    onchange({type: document[hidden] ? "blur" : "focus"});
})();
```

Более подробно про API можно почитать [здесь](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#sec-visibilitychange-event).

Оринальный ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active).